# Can't run azure function locally debug - can't load type Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Scale.IScaleMonitorProvider

Tags: azure, azure-functions

[8/01/2020 5:07:38 AM] A host error has occurred

[8/01/2020 5:07:38 AM] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Scale.IScaleMonitorProvider' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

It will keep stopping and starting the host, spitting out the same message until it gets an OutOfMemoryException.

Additional Info:
The azure function project was running fine on another PC. The local host settings were copied from it to this PC that is having the problem.

The only other oddity was when running the function for the first time, Visual studio says it is downloading the Azure Functions CLI (or something similar) and the first time it did this it failed  (behind a corporate proxy that blocked it) and visual studio stopped responding. I connected to a different network and it appeared to succeed, but maybe it didn't??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a few different things and resolved it finally by completely deleting the solution and redownloading the source from the repo.

Answer (score 0):

I assume there was version mismatch of function run time that is possible to setup in settings 
[azure function run time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/set-runtime-version)

Comment: Thanks for link - if it ever happens again I will try compare the version in the portal. Also can you remove the extraneous '.' at the end of the url), it prevents chrome from loading and FYI it links to Polish language page. [Here is a link to English page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/azure-functions/set-runtime-version)

Comment: Thanks @camios I fixed link.

Comment: Hi @camios if this will fix problem please mark it as answer.

Comment: I was unable to test your answer because because I already implemented mine which fixed it and I haven't seen the problem again to test your suggestion.